# Libraries under Frameworks folder in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone

Working on an iPhone app. After I built the app (Product -> archive) I looked at the package content. Under Frameworks folder, there are a few libraries I have not used anywhere in the project:

1. libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
2. libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
3. libswiftCoreImage.dylib
4. libswiftDarwin.dylib

Here I have 2 questions to ask:

1. Where do they come from?
2. Is there any way to remove them from the final package?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they are required by some components of the infrastructure used by your app.   Do not try to remove them; Apple works hard to minimize footprint via mechanisms such as "app thinning", so most unnecessary object code will be optimized out of the package delivered to the customer.

Comment: To follow up - is there a way to find out which components in the App that use them?